# Recover windows recycle bin files with linux?

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I have a HD with a backup of my windows 10 recycle bin folder. I can see the files in my file system explorer, but I can't open the images or video files (mp4 and avi). How can I view these recycle bin files in linux?

Note: I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply look for a folder named `$Recycle.Bin` in the top directory of the device or something similar.   You should find all your files in there, only that the filenames are messed up.

Comment: Ive found the files, but the jpg and mp4 files won't open. Do I need to do something special?

Comment: no you don't. They should open ok.